# Accessing AppEngine Application ID

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Application ID in appengine is configured in appengine-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>myid</application>
    <version>0-0-1</version>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Can we acces the application id programmatically in Java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Runtime Environment documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime#The_Environment) you can use `SystemProperty.applicationId.get()` to get the application ID.

Answer (score 0):

Here link to officer document

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/appidentity/#getting_the_application_id

```
ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment().getAppId()
```